# Что означает восклицательный знак перед точкой C#

Tags: c#

```
public static Matrix SetMatrix(string path)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
        {
            string? line = sr.ReadLine();
            var size = line!.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries | StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            Matrix a = new Matrix(Int32.Parse(size[0]), Int32.Parse(size[1]));
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Row; i++)
            {
                line = sr.ReadLine();
                var values = line!.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries | StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                for (int j = 0; j < a.Column; j++)
                {
                    a[i, j] = Double.Parse(values[j]);
                }
            }
            return a;
        }
    }
```

Такой вопрос, вот в этом месте **var size = line!.Split** если убрать восклицательный знак, то будет предупреждение, что возможно разыменовывается переменная со значением null. Нашел решение поставить восклицательный знак, а что он обозначает так и не нашел. Кто может объяснить

```
public static void SetMatrix(Matrix a)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.Column; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Введите [{i},{j}] элемент матрицы: ");
                a[i, j] = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }
        }
    }
```

И вот в этом методе в строке **a[i, j] = Double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());** такое же предупреждение, но его не знаю как решить. Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`string?` - это нулейбл вариант стринга. То есть стринг, который может иметь значение `null`

эта возможность потянула за собой появление новых операторов как `?.` и `!.`

`?.` - обращаемся к нулейбл переменной учитывая что переменная может быть `null`. Если налл - то не вызываем метод или не обращаемся к проперте после точки, а возвращаем так же налл вместо этого.

`!.` - мы гарантируем системе что в этой переменной не может быть `null`, после чего мы обращаемся к проперте или методу.

Comment: Объективности ради нужно заметить, что null-conditional operator (?. и ?[]) появился в языке гораздо раньше nullable reference types: первые - это C# 6.0, вторые - C# 8.0.

Answer (score 3):

Это null-forgiving operator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving
Появился, если мне не изменяет память, в C# 8.0